# awswrangler returning dataframes with different dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using *awswrangler* to convert a simple dataframe to parquet push it to an s3 bucket and then read it again.  This is the code:

```
import boto3
import awswrangler as wr
import pandas as pd
test_bucket = 'test-bucket'
test_data = 'test_data.parquet'
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
        [[1990, 1], [2000, 2], [1985, 6]], columns=["Feature1", "Feature2"]
    )
wr.s3.to_parquet(df=df1, path=f"s3://{test_bucket}/{test_data}")
raw_data_s3_objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket=test_bucket)

for path in raw_data_s3_objects["Contents"]:
    file_name = path["Key"]
    raw_dataset = wr.s3.read_parquet(path=f"s3://{test_bucket}/{file_name}")
```

When I print the original dataframe (df1) and the outputted dataframe (raw_dataset) i'm getting (int64 and Int64) dtypes

```
print(df1.dtypes)
print(raw_dataset.dtypes)
Feature1    int64
Feature2    int64
dtype: object
Feature1    Int64
Feature2    Int64
dtype: object
```

which result in the dataframes not being equal. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is, that the difference here is between numpy and pandas types. `int64` stands for numpy type (`np.int64`) and `Int64` for pandas type (`pd.Int64Dtype`).

This was reported in https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/issues/580 and there was some reason for that, but this was "fixed" in realease 2.6.0. Now, you can do that by using `map_types` parameter (default is `True` which does the conversion you do not want):

```
raw_dataset = wr.s3.read_parquet(path=f"s3://{test_bucket}/{file_name}", map_types=False)
```